# jQuery why is my function not executing from array?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have some functions assigned to variable `filterFns`:

```
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -or
  endswithor: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.title').text();
    return name.match( /or$/ );
  }
};
```

I have an array which is assigned to variable `filters`:

```
var filters = [];
```

I have a script that on button click will add (or remove) the data of the clicked button's `data-target` attribute to the `filters` array. Then this array is sent to isotope.js which does some nice layout stuff.

```
var $filters = $('#excl_filters').on( 'click', 'button', function( event ) {
  
var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
$target.toggleClass('is-checked');
var isChecked = $target.hasClass('is-checked');

var filter = $target.attr('data-filter');

  if ( isChecked ) {
    addFilter( filter );

  } else {
    removeFilter( filter );
  }

// send the array to isotope for filtering.

$grid.isotope({ filter: filters.join('') });
  
// For debugging purposes, print what is in the 'filters' array. 

    $.each(filters, function(key, value){
      $("#debug").append(value + '<br>');
    });

});

// These are to add/remove stuff from the array

function addFilter( filter ) {
  if ( filters.indexOf( filter ) == -1 ) {
    filters.push( filter );
  }
}

function removeFilter( filter ) {
  var index = filters.indexOf( filter );
  if ( index != -1 ) {
    filters.splice( index, 1 );
  }
}
```

I can see that when the button is clicked that `endswithor` (the name of my function) data is passed to the array (proven by printing the array data in #debug).

**Why then is the 'endswithor' function not executed?**

Please see below for snippet/simplified example:

```js
  // init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
  }); 
  
  var filterFns = {
      // show if number is greater than 50
      numberGreaterThan50: function() {
        var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
        return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
      },
      // show if name ends with -or
      endswithor: function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.title').text();
        return name.match( /or$/ );
      }
  };

    var filters = [];


  var $filters = $('#excl_filters').on( 'click', 'button',  function( event ) {
      
    var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
    $target.toggleClass('is-checked');
    var isChecked = $target.hasClass('is-checked');
    
    var filter = $target.attr('data-filter');
    
      if ( isChecked ) {
        addFilter( filter );
    
      } else {
        removeFilter( filter );
      }
    
    // Send the array to isotope for filtering.

    $grid.isotope({ filter: filters.join('') });
      
    // For debugging purposes, print what is in the 'filters' array. 

        $.each(filters, function(key, value){
          $("#debug").append(value + '<br>');
        });

    });

    // These are to add/remove stuff from the array

    function addFilter( filter ) {
      if ( filters.indexOf( filter ) == -1 ) {
        filters.push( filter );
      }
    }
    
    function removeFilter( filter ) {
      var index = filters.indexOf( filter );
      if ( index != -1 ) {
        filters.splice( index, 1 );
      }
    }
```

```css
.is-checked {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include jQuery and Isotope libraries -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

Instructions: Click the 'Thor' button (the one that is supposed to make function execute) and note the debugging area.
Note that the 'endswithor' function is passed to array, but the 'Thor' div does not display (because the function does not execute).
<br><br>
<!-- start filter buttons -->

<div id="excl_filters">
Exclusive filters:
    <button class="button" data-filter=".odin">Odin</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".frigg">Frigg</button>
        <button class="button" data-filter="endswithor">Thor</button>
  
</div>

<!-- end filter buttons -->

<br>

<!-- start items to be filtered -->

<div class="grid">
    
    <div class="element-item odin">Odin</div>
    <div class="element-item frigg">Frigg</div>
    <div class="element-item"><span class="title">Thor</span>

</div>

</div>

<!-- end items to be filtered -->

<!-- debugging -->

<br>

------------------<br>
Debugging (contents of the array):
<div id="debug"></div>
------------------<br>
<br>
Note that the other filters are working (the ones that use css classes) but not the one which uses my function 'searchthor'.
```

Comment: Can't see where you pass your fltersFn to isotype - can see the css filters: `$grid.isotope({ filter: filters.join('') });`

Comment: Ok, found it in the [samples](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html):  `filter = filterFns[filter] || filter;` - but that won't work with how you're then joining the array with `.join('')` as it's not a string.  You can't combine functions and strings like that.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. 

So there is no way I can get the function working with the array/string system? No way I can tell isotope to see if the string matches the name of the function, then execute it?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, at least not without changing `proto._getFilterTest`  - it checks if `filter` is a (single) function or a (single) string.

Comment: Alright thanks for your insight, appreciate it :) I'm going to try a different approach to the inclusive/exclusive combination filtering that can accommodate the functions as well.